# Atomic '1.1.14' could not installed in Windows Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, atomic

Couldn't run `bundle install` due to `atomic` gems not installed in Windows Rails. Also tried to install `atomic` gem but can't install. Can anyone please help me out there?

```
C:\site>bundle install
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.1.1
Using i18n 0.6.9
Using minitest 4.7.5
Using multi_json 1.8.4

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read
server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/gems/atomi
c-1.1.14.gem)
An error occurred while installing atomic (1.1.14), and Bundler cannot continue.

Make sure that `gem install atomic -v '1.1.14'` succeeds before bundling.

C:\site>gem install atomic -v '1.1.14'
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'atomic' (= 1.1.14), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect retur
ned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (
https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known error](http://help.rubygems.org/discussions/problems/19586-gem-install-gets-certificate-error). Thankfully, there is a [published workaround](https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88) for it.